# JS compare function that returns closure

Tags: javascript, function, compare, closures

The following code snippet shows the comparison of a few method calls.

```js
console.clear();
const al = (sub, property) => (state) => (state[sub][property]);

const getPatient = (property) => al('patient', property);
const getAppointment = (property) => al('appointment', property);

const state = {
  patient: {name: 'jos', lastname: 'ke'},
  appointment: {date: '01-01-1900'},
};

getPatient('name') === getPatient('lastname'); // should evaluate to false
getPatient('name') === getAppointment('date'); // should evaluate to false
getPatient('name') === getPatient('name'); // should evaluate to true, but is false
```

However, I would like the last comparison to result to `true`. How can we write the comparison so it evaluates to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

The functions `getPatient`, `getAppointment` and `getPatient` return a closure; each time you call those functions, a new closure is returned and they will not be strictly equivalent (`===`).

If you need to create those closures and be able to compare them, only create the closures once and assign them to a variable:

```
const getPatientName = getPatient('name');
```